# Fortran Error: /var/folders/df/btj2wstn58xf0yrmq9n65ybc0000gn/T//ccLHoofN.s:12187:2: error: unsupported symbol modifier in relocation

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am having an error compiling a Fortran script. The full error is presented below.

```
/var/folders/df/btj2wstn58xf0yrmq9n65ybc0000gn/T//ccLHoofN.s:12187:2: error: unsupported symbol modifier in relocation
        movabsq $24044020+_ml_ret.5599@GOTOFF, %rdx
        ^
```

I found where the error occurs but I don't understand why.  Below is an example of the script I am using.

```
      real ml_ret(nx_max,ny_max,nz_max)
      real ml_ret_z(nz_max)

      do j=1,ny
        do i=1,nx
           do k=1,nz_max
              ml_ret_z(k) = ml_ret(i,j,k)
           enddo

          CALL SNOWPACK_CORE(ml_ret_z)

          do k=1,nz_max
            ml_ret(i,j,k) = ml_ret_z(k)
          enddo
        enddo
      enddo
```

Everything compiles and runs except when I add the second k do loop.  Is there something I am missing when building and an array or filling values into the array?

I am using gfortran and running it on a MacBook Pro OS 10.15.5

Any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Fortran does not have scripts.  It has program units.  Anyhow, what compiler and compiler options are you using?

Comment: I am using gfortran and running it on a MacBook Pro OS 10.15.5

Comment: You're clearly generating code for a cpu that you do not have.

Comment: @evets, could you clarify what this error code is referring to?

Comment: The error is coming from ld, the loader, on your system.  It either does not recognize the assembly instruction movabsq or the first operand `$24044020+_ml_ret.5599@GOTOFF`.  (Un)Fortunately, I don't use Macs, so you'll need someone who does to help you.